# UWP InAppNotification

Tags: uwp

Help me somebody.

I'm using InAppNotification in my app with DataGrid and when I show InAppNotification it is transparent and I can't click on this.

**transparent InAppNotification :-**

[image]

```
<MSControls:InAppNotification Grid.Row="1"
                              x:Name="MessageForUser"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Right">
</MSControls:InAppNotification>


private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageForUser.Show("Hello World!", 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `InAppNotification` itself is just like `Popup`, you need to add `Click` or `Tap` event. Just like below.

```
<MSControls:InAppNotification Grid.Row="1"
                              x:Name="MessageForUser"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                              Tapped="MessageForUser_Tapped">
</MSControls:InAppNotification>
```

Comment: i don't understand, you would like say that I should connect InAppNotification to DataGrid?

Comment: Can you clearify click on what, `DataGrid` or `InAppNotification`.

Comment: I have button "AddObjectToDataGrid" and DataGrid on the page before adding i need to validate object and show message for user if something wrong.
I did it but my InAppNotification transparent and i can see through it.

Comment: You mean preventing user seeing through notification? Then you can add `Background` property.

Comment: I added Background property, This is don't help.
[qwerty][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghgd7.jpg

Comment: I uploaded a repo with a `DataGrid` and a `InAppNotification` to github. I added `Background` property, and didn't reproduce the bug you said. See https://github.com/hupo376787/InAppNotification-.